# Table works correctly only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Please, can someone explain why my classic PHP table only showing correct in Chrome, but in Firefox or IE content of the table goes outside of the `<div>`? Everything that is in `style.css` effect correctly on table while displaying in Chrome, but don't react in Firefox or IE.
My table:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$sqlget="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp_oglas DESC";
$sqldata= mysql_query($sqlget);
echo"<table>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo"<b><font color='#e73535'>".$row['heading']."</font></b>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $row['text'];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<img src=\"download.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><br />\n";
echo "<div style='text-align:right'><font size='1px'>".$row['timestamp']."     </font></div>";
echo '<br />';
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo"</table>";?>
```

My `.css`:

```
table{width:95%;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;margin-top:25px;}
```

Screenshot (Chrome):

http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/9603/r40m.png

Screenshot (Firefox): 
[image]

Comment: Including screenshots might help.

Comment: You refer to a `<div>` but there is none in the example.  You also refer to CSS but didn't post any.

Comment: Chances that this is a PHP problem are low...

Comment: You have to give us some more html. We cannnot guess it.

Comment: There are not any problems present within the little code you have posted, therefore no answers can be provided.

Comment: Create http://jsfiddle.net/ with more HTML code and CSS, obviously there is not enough information to solve this "PHP" problem.

Comment: In the images you have provided, the content is identical other then the black semi transparent overlay. This could be a `z-index` issue. Have you got a link to the site or a jsFiddle??

Comment: @newbie Thanks. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/99Zda/

Comment: View source _after_ the page has been rendered and copy and paste the html for that table and the CSS that you're using and update your jsfiddle with this. You can't use PHP in jsfiddle!

Comment: I should point out that you are using several obsolete and deprecated techniques. (1) The `<font>` tag is deprecated; you should use CSS to set your font sizes instead. (2) PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated; you should use either the `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library instead. (3) Using HTML tables for page layout is considered bad practice (I don't even know why you're using a table here anyway, since there's only one cell. You may as well just use a single `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the sollution. I added this line `table-layout: fixed;` in `style.css`. Now works perfectly all browsers.